# Looking for easy to use remote server monitoring tool for Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: monitoring, windows-server-2008-r2, performance-monitoring

We are a very small ecommerce business and we are trying to find a remote monitoring tool something in the lines of the ResMon/PerfMon in Windows in order to monitor our dedicated Windows 2008 R2 server. The main features we need are:

- Easy to use
- Remote monitoring
- Monitors CPU, Memory, HDD, Network
- Ability to monitor IIS, Application Pools and IIS Worker processes remotely
- SQL Server Monitoring
- Alerts based on rules
- We prefer Open Source/Free/Low cost solutions

Any suggestions? I found PowerAdmin ServerMonitor, Munin, Nagios, OpManager, OpMon etc searching google but I don't have time to setup & evaluate everything.

Comment: "I don't have time to setup & evaluate everything" but you're going to take the word of complete strangers on the internet o_O

Comment: I have to admit, that statement kind of rubbed me the wrong way.  It demeans the rest of us, who are all very busy in our own right.  Why should I offer up suggestions to you based on my experience when I'm just as damn busy as you are?  How do you think I gleaned that experience?  That's right, I freed up the time to setup and evaluate everything by coming in on weekends and after hours.

Comment: Isn't that the point of SF and forums in general: One day we ask for recommendations and best practices so that we don't reinvent the wheel knowing that the permanent answer may help others in the same situation.  In that instance we ride on the work of others.  The next day we give back by answering questions when and where we can help.

Comment: @Ed:  So if my recommendations are PowerAdmin, Munin, Nagios, OpManager or OpMon, his answer is going to be the same...s/he doesn't have time to test them.  I'm all for not reinventing the wheel but the statement at the end of the question, indicated to me that there wasn't going to be a give/take situation, since he doesn't have the time.

Comment: From my experience a Q&A forum is exactly that. PLEASE don't spam in here and try to be productive. Every answer in this question contained a different product/solution. If the public opinion favors one product over the others I will gladly try it on my own and consume some hours working on it and evaluating. But why start evaluating EVERY MONITORING SOFTWARE if someone did it before me and is kind enough to share.

Comment: @GregD: WHICH ONE? DO YOU USE THEM ALL?

Comment: @gmakrygiannis:  What you said just above this comment makes a lot more sense to me.  My apologies for taking it the wrong way and not giving you the benefit of the doubt.  Let us know what you ended up choosing...

Comment: I'll come back with my findings after 3-4 days.

Answer (score 1):

check http://simpleservermonitor.codeplex.com/. I am using this. If you have developer you can also customize it.

Prtg is also another good options.

Comment: I think that simpleservermonitor is great, I am definitely going to give it a try. It's inactive for a while. Do you know if it is going to work on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine?

Comment: Yes, it is working with Windows 7. I believe it should work with R2 as well.

Comment: I found a demo that uses Windows Server 2008 R2 so it is supported. I am definitely going to try that.

Comment: Per the FAQ, please do not include a signature in your posts. I've gone through and removed your sig from all of your previous posts.

Answer (score 0):

Try Intellipool.

http://www.intellipool.se/

Answer (score 0):

Try Hyperic, very easy to deploy, to manage and monitor. And it's free!

[Hyperic](http://www.springsource.com/landing/hyperic-open-source-download)

Comment: I just downloaded it, coming from VMware I am expecting a top quality product. I am going to evaluate it and come back with feedback.

Answer (score 0):

We had used Zenoss Core for a while but it ended up being a pain for our Windows servers.. it looked like Enterprise was probably better, but we weren't ready to cough up that much for it. We switched to IPHostMonitor and it's been working great for us so far :-) Not open source, but it's the best "low cost" solution I could find.  http://www.iphostmonitor.com/

Comment: It looks nice, but since spiceworks, hyperic and ssm are free I think I should give them a try first.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com), (free but ad supported) it is supposedly easy to use & fairly comprehensive.  We use something else because our needs are different but this seems to get good feedback for similar situations.

Answer (score 0):

Try appfirst. It does all of what you are asking for and is easy to validate because it's a SAAS tool.